# Should I combine my SASS output (multiple files) into a single file? If so, how?

Tags: html, css, sass

I used to have one scss file, and turn it into one css file and use that in my html. I now want to reorganise my stuff, and use multiple scss files, split into a `main.scss`, `buttons.scss` etc.

However, if I am correct, the output will then also be in multiple `.css` files, i.e. I *cannot* tell SASS to combine them all into one file.

How would I best include these multiple files into my html? Is there a way to combine all of them again and have a single `.css` file, or should I rather load them as separate files in my different pages, as needed?

If it is better to use a single file in the end, which I suppose it is, can I tell SASS to combine my `.scss` files into a single `.css` file, or would I use a different tool for that?

Comment: You can include files in one file via `@import` and name the imports starting with an underscore (then, they won't be turned into a CSS file). If you combine all to one, you have one big file, but only one request. If you have multiple files, you have smaller files and you can separate them to different views/components, but you have more requests of course. Trade-off between size and requests/latency.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look into files called "Partials". You would name your files like this

```
_buttons.scss
_lists.scss
```

Then create a main.scss file(name it whatever you want). enter

```
@import buttons
@import lists
```

Then convert your main.scss file to css. You will have one css file. You can read up on this at the SASS website

http://sass-lang.com/guide

If you use SMACSS or other methods, in each directory you would do this. For instance a layout directory

```
Layout
_buttons.scss
_list.scss
_layout-dir.scss
```

In the layout-dir file you would import all the files in the layout directory
then in your main.scss file you would only import each directory file

```
@import layout/layout-dir
@import basics/base-dir
```

etc

Your variable and mixins files would also import into the main.scss file, include them first so everything has access to them

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GI1BhlDtoUs

Comment: The syntax is `@import 'partial_name';`

Comment: @Miscreant  that is the syntax, however I am used to using SMACSS. Which of course uses 4-5 different directories. Each directory, say the layout directory, has a directory file which ends in -dir. The vid I linked to shows that usage

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-5):

> Sass builds on top
>   of the current CSS @import but instead of requiring an HTTP request,
>   Sass will take the file that you want to import and combine it with
>   the file you're importing into so you can serve a single CSS file to
>   the web browser.
>
> ```
> // _reset.scss
>
> html,
> body,
> ul,
> ol {
>    margin: 0;
>   padding: 0;
> }
> // base.scss
>
> @import 'reset';
>
> body {
>   font: 100% Helvetica, sans-serif;
>   background-color: #efefef;
> }
> ```